# EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'details'

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, components, router

I have this router:

```
import { Route, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ProjectDetailsComponent } from '../components/project-details/project-details.component';

export const ROUTES: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/details',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'details/:id',
    component: ProjectDetailsComponent
  }
];
```

Also I have an appropriate controller, named ProjectDetailsComponent.

This is my app module, in which I have registered my routes:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Custom components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProjectDetailsComponent } from './components/project-details/project-details.component';

// Routes
import { ROUTES } from './services/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, ProjectDetailsComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

And its my app.component, in which I try to redirect to ProjectDetailsComponent using "/details" routes and send to it project id:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IProject } from './domain/projects
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
// Routes
import { ROUTES } from './services/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'projects-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    public activeProject: IProject;
    public projects: Array<IProject>;

    constructor(public router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.navigate(['/details', this.activeProject.Id]);
    }
}
```

But when I try to navigate to 'details/:id' router I get following error:

```
C:\Sources\SolarPro\build\debug\resources\app\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:3521 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): 
   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'details'
```

Please help me with my problem.

Comment: if you browse directly to `<server_url>/details/1` does it work?

Comment: I use Angular2 in the electron app and I don't know how I can check this way. If I try change location by using `window.location.assing()` it doesn't work as expected. But if I use
`this.router.navigateByUrl("/app/details/1");`
I get the previous error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect is going to `/details` which doesn't have a component defined. You need to define a component for `/details`.

routes.ts

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/details',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'details',
    component: DetailsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'details/:id',
    component: ProjectDetailsComponent
  }
];
```

details.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['/details', 1]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried this way. But I always get to the `DetailsComponent` instead of `ProjectDetailsComponent`, even if I passed the `id`. If I set the same component to all routes, I always get to the `ProjectDetailsComponent` as expected, but I can't get `id`, because it is undefined.

Comment: Did you add a router-outlet to your app.component.html?

Comment: Yes. I did it.
`<div class="projects-panel">
    <project-list [(selected)]="activeProject" [projects]="projects"></project-list>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>`

Comment: I beleave, this proves that the outlet works. And routing partially works. But for some reason it does not determine the route with parameters.

Comment: This worked for me, try simplifying your problem and look at the angular tutorial for routing.

Comment: I added simple `DetailsComponent` component, as in your example, that only redirect me to another component and send`id = 1` to it . And it works! But I can't understand why this is not working, if I try to go directly to the desired component.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue apply, all possible solution but finally, this solve my problem

```
export class AppRoutingModule {
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.errorHandler = (error: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['details']); // or redirect to default route
    }
  }
}
```

This will work because angular 4 has not given any default route so handle error catch that and you can redirect to default route